# PHP XML Parse to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, cron

My question is based more on theory than syntax, but any syntax suggestions are more than welcome.  My project has a larger scope and a smaller scope.  I will explain both, but I'm most concerned about the smaller scope immediately.  Any suggestions for the larger scope are welcome.

The shorthand of what I need to accomplish(smaller scope):

Parse multiple(2-4) xml files.  Target a single element that reoccurs.  Insert the data from within that element(a string of characters) into mySQL from each occurrence.  Read back from the database how many rows of that data were inserted(I only need a count of how many times that element occurred in each file, I'm not immediately concerned with the data within the element).
I still need to store the data, but once again am ultimately only concerned with how many times the element showed up in each xml file.  I will then need to echo back the summation for each xml file, and ultimately e-mail the results.

For the larger scope:  Eventually this script will need to be automated.  It will need to, once an hour, be scheduled to look for new occurrences of these xml files that are stored on a local server, inserted in mySQL, then echo back the new summation for that hour.  My thought for this would be cron jobs.

I know this is a very loaded question, but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time for any help/suggestions.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What approach are you thinking of taking? StackOverflow is not designed to really be a "Tell me how to do this" site.

Comment: What have you tried, like Mike said... and also: why parse, insert, count, echo and then parse again? if you're not going to store your data in MySQL, why not parse the document and count the nodes

Comment: I realize now my question was kind of vague.  I guess, here is my bottleneck.  I'm not very familiar with PHP's XML functions/classes, or working with XML files in general.  Also the fact that I need to parse more than one.  OOP is also a fairly new concept to me as well.  So, my question lies mostly in, what's the best parser function/class for what I need to do(listed in my question above).  And, since I have more than one, should I just create multiple class instances, or can I parse multiple files within the same instance?

Comment: Pretty much you can use the same instance of the database object, IE mysqli, but when it comes to SimpleXML you would create a new object for each XML file you want to parse.  Also if you're getting the files via a connection, then you'd need another instance of whatever wrapper class you setup around cURL if any.  I guess it's safe to say that most of the time you need a new object each time, most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to start writing the script, setup a DB connection, use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), and yeah, unless you can trigger the script using organic traffic, just crontab it.

It's not really difficult, it's just the fact that it's a labor intensive script to write.

But you can do something like this (pseudo code)...

```
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    foreach($XML->elements as $XML)
    {
     if(isset($XML->tag_you_are_looking_for))
     {
      //Insert $XML->tag_you_are_looking_for to DB
     }
    }
```

For Multiple files, just loop the parser class you made.  For remote files, get them first using [cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

My suggestion overall is just start with those things in mind and if you have any more specific problems you run into, ask those questions separately.